# no_rest_route error on custom routes

Tags: php, plugin-development, rest-api, routing

I'm trying to set up a custom endpoint.

I've been following https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ but I can't get the route to register.

Below is my code.

```
<?php
        
 add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_plugin_routes');
    
 function register_plugin_routes()
 {
    
        register_rest_route( 'mchs/v1', '/test',
            [
                'methods'   => 'GET',
                'callback'  => 'mchs_test'
            ]
        );
    
        register_rest_route( 'mchs/v1', '/search/?P<search_email>\S+',
            [
                'methods'   => ['GET','POST'],
                'callback'  => 'mchs_search_by_email',
                'args'      => [
                    'search_email'  => [
                        'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                            return is_email( $param );
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
    
    function mchs_search_by_email( WP_REST_Request $request )
    {
        $param = $request->get_param('search_email');
    
        return search_hubspot( $param );
    }
    
    function mchs_test ( WP_REST_REQUEST $request )
    {
        return "This is a test.";
    }
```

The route I'm trying to access is http://site.test/wp-json/mchs/v1/search/john@example.com

Using http://site.test/wp-json/mchs/v1/search?search_email=john@example.com doesn't work either.

There is no indication of why anything is failing, all I get in response is

```
{
  "code": "rest_no_route",
  "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method.",
  "data": {
    "status": 404
  }
}
```

I know the script is loading because I can call http://site.test/wp-json/mchs/v1/test and get a successful response.

What's wrong with my call to register_rest_route() ? Is it the way I'm trying to access it?

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's wrong with my call to register_rest_route() ? Is it the way I'm
> trying to access it?

This is the correct way to access that endpoint:

> The route I'm trying to access is
> `http://site.test/wp-json/mchs/v1/search/john@example.com`

But then you're getting the 404 error because the [**path variable**](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#path-variables) in the *second parameter* below, is not in the correct form of `(?P<parameter name>regular expression pattern)`, **including the *round brackets* ( `(` and `)` )**:

```php
register_rest_route( 'mchs/v1', '/search/?P<search_email>\S+',
```

So you're just missing the round brackets and thus just add them, i.e. use `(?P<search_email>\S+)`, and the 404 error would be gone:

```php
register_rest_route( 'mchs/v1', '/search/(?P<search_email>\S+)',
```

Additionally, you should *always set a [`permission_callback`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback)*, even for public REST API routes, to avoid a `_doing_it_wrong` notice. :)